# Event propagation and function that works only on the first div

Tags: html

I have a multiple div with texts. I have a function that on click (in each part of the screen) change background color and slides text with the next. I also wanted a copy to clipboard button for each poetry and an alert that return a message with "author" returned.
I succeded on click to copy and return the alert message but it applies only to the first div. What is the problem? Is there also a problem of event propagation?

This is the code. I hope someone could give me an insight! Thanks in advance, I'm a newbie :D

````
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 700px;}

.mySlides{
position: absolute;padding: 15px; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}


body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}



p {
font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Baskerville';
}
 
.author {
     padding-top:50px !important;
     text-align: right;
 }
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="btn" class="totale">
<div id="btn" class="container">

<div id="bottone" class="mySlides"><p>Text1</p><p class="author">Author1</p><button type="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('bottone','author')">Copy text</button></div>

<div id="bottone" class="mySlides"><p>Text2</p><p class="author">Author2</p><button type="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('bottone','author')">Copy text</button></div>

<div id="bottone" class="mySlides"><p>Text3</p><p class="author">Author3</p><button type="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('bottone','author')">Copy text</button></div>

</div>
</div>

<script>

/*FUNCTION CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR AND SLIDES */

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const body = document.body;
const colors = ['#3141AD','#FF9964','#00BAA4','#DF4D44','#514399','#015CCA']

body.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]

button.addEventListener('click',() => {    
     changeBackground();
     plusSlides(1);    
});

function changeBackground(){
const colorsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)
body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorsIndex]
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 }

/*FUNCTION COPY TEXT*/
function CopyToClipboard(id){
    var r = document.createRange();
    r.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
    var q = document.createRange();
    q.selectNode(document.getElementById('author'));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(r);
    
    try {
        document.execCommand('copy');
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        
        alert('Text copied! ' +q  +' will thank you');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Unable to copy!');
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `id` values that are the same.  `id`s need to be unique across the whole document.  Since you are doing `document.getElementById(id)` you are only returning the first element that matches the id passed.

I would refactor that function, and make use of the `event.target`, which is a parameter that gets passed to all events, such as `"click"`.

Change buttons to pass in the `event` to `copyToClipboard`.

```
<div id="btn" class="totale">
  <div id="btn" class="container">
    <div id="bottone" class="mySlides">
      <p>Text1</p>
      <p class="author">Author1</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard(event)">Copy text</button>
    </div>

    <div id="botttwo" class="mySlides">
      <p>Text2</p>
      <p class="author">Author2</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard(event)">Copy text</button>
    </div>

    <div id="bottthree" class="mySlides">
      <p>Text3</p>
      <p class="author">Author3</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard(event)">Copy text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the function, I change it to camelCase, because PascalCase is loosely reserved for Objects, or other framework specific modules.

Also, you were calling `getElementById` on `"authors"`, but again, the same problem as before, except this time, those elements have the class of `"authors"`, not id, so it's ok to have more than one per page.

I changed the lookup for authors by using the `e.target.previousElementSibling` since the author element is just above the button in document order.

```
function copyToClipboard(e) {
  var r = document.createRange()
  r.selectNode(e.target)
  var q = document.createRange()
  q.selectNode(e.target.previousElementSibling())
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  window.getSelection().addRange(r)

  try {
    document.execCommand("copy")
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()

    alert("Text copied! " + q + " will thank you")
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Unable to copy!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answer!
I used your code, replacing my div and my copy to clipboard function but it doesn't work. Did you try it? It doesn't copy anything. It only slides ( cause my sliding function).